# Add to int filed each time an action called?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I want to increase 1 unit of my int field named `BookViews` by per action run.

**My Action :**

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult BookDetails(int id)
 {
     MultiModels model = new MultiModels();
     model.UserListed = (from u in _userManager.Users orderby u.Id descending select u).Take(10).ToList();


        using (var db = _iServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>())
        {
            var result = from b in db.books where (b.BookId == id) select b;

            if (result.Count() != 0)
            {
                ///error occure here
                db.books.Update((from b in db.books where b.BookId == id select b.BookViews) + 1));
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

But my code get error. How can i increase `BookViews` field 1 unit per run and update it in database?

Comment: what error? post the exception and which line the exception is thrown

Comment: if you are ok with raw sql then. UPDATE Book SET BookViews = BookViews + 1 WHERE ID = @id

Comment: @Steve No i use code first entityFramework

Comment: The `result` var is the current Book?

Comment: @MatheusCuba yes

Comment: Just one more question, this `Update()` that you call from your `context`, are you using a custom implemented method or just the native `Update()` from EF?

Comment: @MatheusCuba it is native Update() from EF and i want to update `BookView` field and increase 1 digit per run

Comment: Please don't force tags into the question title, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging on how to correctly use tags

Comment: Voting to close as you haven't provided the exception details that were asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try retrieving the book that you want, increment your `BookViews` and then call `SaveChanges()`:

```
var currentBook = result.ToList().FirstOrDefault();

if(currentBook != null){

    currentBook.BookViews++;

    db.Books.Attach(currentBook );
    //Changing the State
    db.Entry(currentBook ).State = EntityState.Modified;

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Edit**

Please try to be more especific, we are reallt trying to help you, but I **cant't** guess the error's that you are getting or what the varibles in your code do, if you don't explain...

Comment: This line has an error `result.BookViews++` 
`result` dont Contain a definition for `BookViews`

Comment: What is `result` `Type()`?

Comment: This is specified in the question text

Comment: `ToList`, `Attach` and setting state are redundant. The explanation at the beginning is good, why don't you simply follow it with the code :)

Comment: Sure @IvanStoev!, you mean like this? `result.FirstOrDefault()?BookViews++.` and then call `SaveChanges()`?. Sorry if I'm wrong, in the project that I work we update Object's in that way